# Htaccess : How To Redirect https to http ignoring one folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I just tried to add the following htaccess rules to redirect all https urls (www and non www) (except /wp-admin folder and everything inside it) to http (non www). But when its added, it started to give me redirection loops! Know why its happening?

PS: I'm also using w3Total Cache plugin and it have a lot of rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 !^wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://techhamlet.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here is my whole htaccess file :

```
# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION</code>
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

# REDIRECT to FEEDBURNER
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* http://feeds.feedburner.com/techhamlet [L,R=302]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/comments/feed/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* http://feeds.feedburner.com/techhamlet/comments [L,R=302]
</IfModule>

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/+(wp-admin/|wp-login\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2\.0\ mmp|240x320|alcatel|amoi|asus|au\-mic|audiovox|avantgo|benq|bird|blackberry|blazer|cdm|cellphone|danger|ddipocket|docomo|dopod|elaine/3\.0|ericsson|eudoraweb|fly|haier|hiptop|hp\.ipaq|htc|huawei|i\-mobile|iemobile|j\-phone|kddi|konka|kwc|kyocera/wx310k|lenovo|lg|lg/u990|lge\ vx|midp|midp\-2\.0|mmef20|mmp|mobilephone|mot\-v|motorola|netfront|newgen|newt|nintendo\ ds|nintendo\ wii|nitro|nokia|novarra|o2|openweb|opera\ mobi|opera\.mobi|palm|panasonic|pantech|pdxgw|pg|philips|phone|playstation\ portable|portalmmm|ppc|proxinet|psp|pt|qtek|sagem|samsung|sanyo|sch|sec|sendo|sgh|sharp|sharp\-tq\-gx10|small|smartphone|softbank|sonyericsson|sph|symbian|symbian\ os|symbianos|toshiba|treo|ts21i\-10|up\.browser|up\.link|uts|vertu|vodafone|wap|willcome|windows\ ce|windows\.ce|winwap|xda|zte) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_low]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (acer\ s100|android|archos5|blackberry9500|blackberry9530|blackberry9550|cupcake|docomo\ ht\-03a|dream|htc\ hero|htc\ magic|htc_dream|htc_magic|incognito|ipad|iphone|ipod|lg\-gw620|liquid\ build|maemo|mot\-mb200|mot\-mb300|nexus\ one|opera\ mini|samsung\-s8000|series60.*webkit|series60/5\.0|sonyericssone10|sonyericssonu20|sonyericssonx10|t\-mobile\ mytouch\ 3g|t\-mobile\ opal|tattoo|webmate|webos) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_high]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:.gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|wp-.*\.php|index\.php) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_\[a\-f0\-9\]\+|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
    RewriteCond "/home/techham/public_html/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$1/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule (.*) "/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$1/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: please can you add details of the redirection loop? `wget --spider [url]` should give useful output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/+(wp-admin/|wp-login\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry mate.. it didn't worked :( I added the whole htaccess file in the above question.. Please check it :D

Comment: I looked at your .htaccess as well. If you insert line: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/wp-admin/ [NC]
` right after this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]` in your .htaccess as I showed in my answer above it will work fine. I have tested with your .htaccess with 1 extra line and `/wp-admin/` is not being redirected in my testing.

Comment: Thanks mate.. But it won't redirect https to https... This is what i want... 1) Redirect all https requests to http (except the wp-admin) (wp-admin should use https). 2) Redirect all www urls (including https wp-admin) to non www

Comment: Alright edited answer above. Just copy paste above 4 lines right before `# BEGIN W3TC` line in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks... it works up to a certain extent... Now https with www, redirects to non https non www urls. But... https with non www won't get redirected to http :( know how to fix that?

Comment: Alright look at the modified rule above: esp: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]`

Comment: Sorry my friend.... now the wp-admin is not working! https://techhamlet.com/wp-admin/ (Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly")

Comment: I have tested your combined .htaccess and it is working fine here. I have directly edited your .htaccess in question to include my answer as well. Just copy/paste and see if it works.

Comment: Still not working my friend.. :( In chrome, its working... But Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly".. For the wp-admin only! Others are working perfectly!

Comment: Alright, can you pls clear Firefox cache and restart the browser and then try again.

Comment: Cleared the cache and restarted... Still the same problem :(

Comment: Rewrite rules are not browser dependent. I tried to open your link `https://techhamlet.com/wp-admin/` in Chrome and and even there it is looping with the error: `https://techhamlet.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252Fwww.techhamlet.com%252525252525252525252Fwp-admin%252525252525252525252F&reauth=1 has resulted in too many redirects`

Comment: Most likely you need to have exception for `wp-login.php` as well. See my modified answer above.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot mate! Now everything works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: My pleasure, rules were always right it was just that `wp-admin/index.php` was redirecting to `/wp-logn.php` and that's why creating this issue. Glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
# redirecting HTTPS requests
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS}    =on
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !^wp-admin
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$  http://foo.com/$1    [R=301,L]

# redirecting all requests to have the right host name
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.foo\.com     [NC]
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    !^$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/$1            [R=301,L]
```

The only catch I can see with it is that you must request https://foo.com/wp-admin/ not https://www.foo.com/wp-admin/